Weird Behavior of GameObject Under Pressure - Unity
Why is my cup behaving weirdly when bubbles fall from the top?
Here is the clip of that strange behavior.

I've tweaked some Rigidbody parameters, such as Interpolate, and reduced the mass of the bubble prefab, but it still hasn't fixed the issue.I expect the bubbles to fall into the cup smoothly without causing any erratic movements.
Here are some screenshots of my bubble and cup components


Side note: Initially, the cup's body type is set to Kinematic. When the bubbles start to fall, the cup's body type is dynamically set to Dynamic, and its mass is set to 30 through the code.
I appreciate your HELP!
Thanks 

From the video it appears that the mass of the cup is the same or even less than that of the balls. Do you want the cup to be able to fall? If not, try locking the cup's constraints under
 Rigidbody -> Contrants -> [Choose what you need to lock for your game].
Otherwise, just try increasing the mass.

No, the mass of the cup is 30, while the mass of the bubble is 0.1. I want the cup to be able to move.

I received an answer from my Unity discussions post, which you can see here:
Unity Discussions: Weird Behavior of GameObject Under Pressure

Make sure to flag this as the answer for others!
